# Synchronise Windows 8.1 time with NTP server when booting up

Tags: windows, ntp

I have an issue with BIOS causing time to be reset in 9 of 10 times when system boots up...

While Windows 8.1 somehow trusts the time from BIOS more than NTP, how can I force Windows to synchronise with NTP automatically every time it boots up?

Comment: Actually just after I posted this question, I found this: http://www.thewindowsclub.com/change-internet-time-update-interval-windows

Comment: Perhaps exchange the [CMOS battery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonvolatile_BIOS_memory) as well (the time and date may not be the only thing affected).

Answer (score 2):

Create a batch file to run **w32tm /resync** and place a shortcut to it in the startup folder... http://www.tomshardware.com/faq/id-2080296/add-programs-startup-windows.html

Comment: Can you give a more detailed description of the linked content, and explain how it relates to the question? This will help ensure that this answer remains useful in the event the linked page goes offline.